# XSL compare ids

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

can you tell me why it doesnt work? Im a newbie at xsl....

xsl:

```
<ol id="presents">
<xsl:for-each select="tns:meeting/tns:jobs/tns:ausents/tns:ausent-member">
<li id="ausent"><a HREF="#jobs"><b><xsl:value-of select="tns:meeting/tns:members/tns:member[@member_id = current()/@member_id]/@name"/></b></a></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ol>
```

xml Example:

```
<tns:meeting data="2001-01-01" local="Porto" organization="FCUP" type="ordinária" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/meeting" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/meeting meeting.xsd ">
  <tns:members> 
      <tns:member name="João" member_id="i1" title="account manager"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Carlos" member_id="i2" title="director geral"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="José" member_id="i3" title="colaborador"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Joana" member_id="i4" title="secretária"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Carolina" member_id="i5" title="tesoureira"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Pedro" member_id="i6" title="colaborador"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Ivo" member_id="i7" title="presidente AE"></tns:member>
      <tns:member name="Luis" member_id="i8" title="vice-presidente AE"></tns:member>
  </tns:members>
<tns:jobs> <!-- Possibilidade de colocar o atributo nome no trabalho -->
        <tns:ausents>
            <tns:ausent-member member_id="i1">
                <tns:justification>Problemas pessoais</tns:justification>   
            </tns:ausent-member>
            <tns:ausent-member member_id="i2">
                <tns:justification>Problemas pessoais</tns:justification>   
            </tns:ausent-member>
        </tns:ausents>
```

The step

> "tns:meeting/tns:members/tns:member[@member_id =
>   current()/@member_id]">"

is not working and i cant find the problem....

Comment: Are you sure you have `<xsl:value-of select="...">/>`? Because that's a syntax error.

Comment: my error copying. sorry ;) I dont have it like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of this expression...

```
<xsl:value-of select="tns:meeting/tns:members/tns:member[@member_id = current()/@member_id]/@name">
```

At this point, you are in an xsl:for-each, positioned on a **tns:ausent-member** element, but your **xsl:value-of** is a relative expression. It is relative to the element you are postioned on, and so is looking for a child element called **tns:meeting**.

You need to make it an absolute expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="/tns:meeting/tns:members/tns:member[@member_id = current()/@member_id]/@name">
```

The forward slash at the start means it will start off at the document node, which is what you want.

However, when looking up elements in this way, it is sometimes better to define a key

```
 <xsl:key name="member" match="tns:member" use="@member_id" />
```

Then you can look up the elements like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('member', @member_id)/@name"/>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/meeting">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="member" match="tns:member" use="@member_id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <ol id="presents">
         <xsl:for-each select="tns:meeting/tns:jobs/tns:ausents/tns:ausent-member">
             <li id="ausent"><a HREF="#jobs"><b>
                  <xsl:value-of select="key('member', @member_id)/@name"/>
             </b></a></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </ol>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the `tns:members` and `tns:jobs` are siblings. Inside the `xsl:for-each select="tns:meeting/tns:jobs/tns:ausents/tns:ausent-member"` the context node is an `tns:ausent-member` so you need to go up to

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tns:meeting/tns:members/tns:member[@member_id = current()/@member_id]/@name">
```